# Efficient way of handling large number of data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a scenario and two options to achieve it. Which one will be more efficient?

I am using mySQL to store attendance of students (around 100 million). And later use this attendance data to plot charts and results based on user’s selection.

**Approach.1)** Store attendance data of student for each day in new row (which will increase the number of rows exponentially and reduce processing time)

**Approach.2)** Store serialized or JSON formatted row of one year’s attendance data of each student in a row (Which will increase processing time when updating attendance each day and reduce database size)

Comment: 100k Isn't that much

Comment: 100k vs 100 mill, that's a major edit!

Comment: Sorry... I missed that.

Comment: So you save 100 million rows every day (are you counting student or rabbits :P)? Or have 100 million and is growing daily for how much? Because I still think my answer will work the same.

Comment: No, not 100 million row every day. Approx 1Lac rows every day. I am afraid in long run will it be able to handle such huge number of rows efficiently

Comment: what is `1Lac`? Anyway you should be fine. Possible improvement, create a procedure to move old data to a historic database. Also create some tables where you will save the calculated data instead of saving the raw data.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza 1 lakh is 100,000.  Why did you edit your question from 100,000 to 100,000,000?

Comment: I have an AVL service, I save `x, y` position from every car every min. So also around 100k daily. But I only save 6 months old data in main database. And use some algorithms to predict traffic behaviour, but I compress the raw data into tendency variables.

Comment: @Siyual the exact amount of data is not known, I have mentioned approximate amount. For time being I am going with Juan's approach

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First I think you are confused, the number of rows will increase linear not exponential that is a big difference.

Second 100k is nothing for a database. even if you store 365 days that is only 36 million, I have that in a week,

Third Store in a JSON may complicated future query.

So I suggest go with approach 1

Using proper Index, design and a fast HDD a db can handle billion of records.

Also you may consider save historic data in a different schema so current data is a little faster, but that is just a minor tuneup